# postgres one to many flattened return

Tags: postgresql, one-to-many

I am trying to write a postgres query that uses 3 tables: people, attribute, and a people_attribute join

people table:

`id, name`

attribute table:

`id, name, attr_group`

people_attribute join:

`people_id, attribute_id`

desired output:

```
name    | fav_colors     | fav_music        | fav_foods
-----------------------------------------------------------------
michael | red,blue,green | pop,hip-hop,jazz | pizza,burgers,tacos
bob     | orange,green   | null             | tacos,steak,fish
```

...etc

The tags can vary from none to ~12 for each attr_group

Here is the query I am working with:

```
select 
    p.id,
    p.name,
    (case when a.attr_group like 'fav_colors' then string_agg(a.name, ',') else null end) as fav_colors,
    (case when a.attr_group like 'fav_music' then string_agg(a.name, ',') else null end) as fav_music,
    (case when a.attr_group like 'fav_foods' then string_agg(a.name, ',') else null end) as fav_foods,
from people as p
join people_attribute as pa on pa.people_id = p.id
join "attribute" as a on a.id = pa.attribute_id
group by 1,2,a.attr_group 
order by 1 asc;
```

which returns:

```
name    | fav_colors     | fav_music        | fav_foods
-----------------------------------------------------------------
michael | red,blue,green | null             | null
michael | null           | pop,hip-hop,jazz | null
michael | null           | null             | pizza,burgers,tacos
bob     | null           | null             | null
bob     | orange,green   | null             | null
bob     | null           | null             | tacos,steak,fish
```

I feel like I'm getting close, but am unsure how to flatten this out to achieve the desired output as shown above. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll want to move the `case when` *inside* the (string) aggregate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `filter` for this:

```
select p.id,
       p.name,
       string_agg(a.name, ',') filter (where a.attr_group = 'fav_color') as fav_colors,
       string_agg(a.name, ',') filter (where a.attr_group = 'fav_music') as fav_music,
       string_agg(a.name, ',') filter (where a.attr_group = 'fav_foods') as fav_foods,
  from people as p
       join people_attribute as pa 
         on pa.people_id = p.id
       join "attribute" as a 
         on a.id = pa.attribute_id
  group by p.id, p.name 
  order by 1 asc;
```

Using `filter` passes only values that match the `filter` `where` condition into the aggregation.

The reason yours was showing three rows per `people` record is because you added `attribute.attr_group` to your `group by`.  You had no choice since you were using `attribute.attr_group` in your `case` conditionals.

Using `filter` makes `attribute.attr_group` part of the aggregation, so you do not have to include it in your `group by` list.